# Fast Ray and Polygon Intersection

Tags: c++, polygon, sfml, intersection, raytracing

I'm working on programming my own little game which should have a visibility effect as described [here](http://ncase.me/sight-and-light/). My world consists of Polygons which each have a list of Edges (sorted CW). I now want (as described in the article) to cast Rays towards the Edges of the polygons, find the intersections and retrieve a Polygon that defines the visible area.

So I wrote a classes for Vectors, Points, Edges and Polygons and adjusted the intersection-algorithm so it works with my code.

I then tested it and everything worked fine, but as I ran the Intersection algorithm in a for-loop to simulate a large amount of Edges processed(starting with 100, until 1000) the fps dropped drastically, with 100 Edges "only" 300fps (3000 before), and with 300 it dropped below 60 i think. This seems to be way to much drop for me as i wanted to reuse this code for my Lightsources and then i think i would quickly come up with processing way more than 300 Edges and it should run fast on way less powerful processors(i got an xeon e1230v3).

I figured out that only calling the EdgeIntersection the program runs many times faster, but I definitely need to loop through the Edges in my polygons so this is no option.

My Source-Code:

Vector.h/.cpp: Basic Vector class with two floats(X,Y), getters&setters, rotating

Vertex.h/.cpp: Basic Point class with a Position Vector, getters&setters and a boolean that indicates whether it is a Intersection Vertex

Edge.h/.cpp Basic Edge class with start/end-Verticies, getters&setters and rotating function(uses Vector.rotate())

Polygon.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "Edge.h"

namespace geo
{
class Polygon
{
private:
    std::vector<Edge> edges;

public:
    Polygon();
    Polygon(std::vector<Edge> edges);
    ~Polygon();

    std::vector<Edge> getEdges();
    Edge getEdge(int index);
    int getEdgeCount();

    void setEdges(std::vector<Edge> edges);
    void setEdge(Edge e, int index);
    void addEdge(Edge e);
    void removeEdge(int index);
};
}
```

Ray.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Vertex.h"

class Ray
{
private:
    geo::Vertex origin;
    geo::Vector dir;

public:
    Ray();
    Ray(geo::Vertex origin, geo::Vector dir);
    ~Ray();

    geo::Vertex getOrigin();
    geo::Vector getDirection();

    void setOrigin(geo::Vertex origin);
    void setDirection(geo::Vector dir);
};
```

LightModule.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Polygon.h"
#include "Ray.h"

class LightModule
{
private:
//List of blocking Polygons
std::vector<geo::Polygon>* blockingPolygons;
std::vector<Ray> rays;

geo::Polygon bounds;
geo::Polygon visible;
/*geo::Polygon blocked;*/

//HitDetection Class later
geo::Vertex getIntersection(Ray r, geo::Edge* e);
geo::Vertex getClosestIntersection(Ray r, geo::Polygon *p);
public:
LightModule();
LightModule(std::vector<geo::Polygon>* blockingPolygons);
~LightModule();

//Set the Blocking Polygons
void setBlockingPolygons(std::vector<geo::Polygon>* blockingPolygons);

geo::Vertex callCI(Ray r, geo::Polygon* p);
geo::Vertex callI(Ray r, geo::Edge* e);

//Cast Rays towards Vertecies and store them in rays
void updateRays();
//Update Visibility Polygon
void updateVisible();
//Return Visibility Polygon
geo::Polygon* getVisible();
};
```

LightMModule.cpp:

```
#include "LightModule.h"


LightModule::LightModule()
{
rays.clear();
}

LightModule::LightModule(std::vector<geo::Polygon>* blockingPolygons)
{
this->blockingPolygons = blockingPolygons;
rays.clear();
}

LightModule::~LightModule()
{
}

void LightModule::setBlockingPolygons(std::vector<geo::Polygon>* blockingPolygons)
{
this->blockingPolygons = blockingPolygons;
}

//Test-cast a Ray (will follow mouse in the Test)
void LightModule::updateRays()
{
Ray r(geo::Vertex(geo::Vector(200, 100)), geo::Vector(-100, 0));
rays.push_back(r);

}

void LightModule::updateVisible()
{

}

//Both for Testing will later be part of a seperate class
geo::Vertex LightModule::callCI(Ray r, geo::Polygon *p)
{
return this->getClosestIntersection(r, p);
}

geo::Vertex LightModule::callI(Ray r, geo::Edge* e)
{
return this->getIntersection(r, e);
}



//TEST

geo::Vertex LightModule::getIntersection(Ray r, geo::Edge* e)
{
geo::Vertex v;
v.setIntersectVert(false);

float r_px = r.getOrigin().getPosition().getX();
float r_py = r.getOrigin().getPosition().getY();
float r_dx = r.getDirection().getX();
float r_dy = r.getDirection().getY();

float s_px = e->getOrigin().getPosition().getX();
float s_py = e->getOrigin().getPosition().getY();
float s_dx = e->getDirection().getX();
float s_dy = e->getDirection().getY();

float r_mag = sqrt(r_dx*r_dx + r_dy*r_dy);
float s_mag = sqrt(s_dx*s_dx + s_dy*s_dy);

if (r_dx / r_mag == s_dx / s_mag && r_dy / r_mag == s_dy / s_mag)
{
    return v;
}

float T2 = (r_dx*(s_py - r_py) + r_dy*(r_px - s_px)) / (s_dx*r_dy - s_dy*r_dx);
float T1 = (s_px + s_dx*T2 - r_px) / r_dx;

if (T1 < 0 /*|| T1 > 1 For Lines*/)
{
    return v;
}
if (T2 < 0 || T2 > 1)
{
    return v;
}

v.setIntersectVert(true);
v.setPosition(geo::Vector(r_px + r_dx*T1, r_py + r_dy*T1));
return v;
}

geo::Vertex LightModule::getClosestIntersection(Ray r, geo::Polygon *p)
{
geo::Vertex v;
v.setIntersectVert(false);
geo::Vertex v_nearest(geo::Vector(0, 0));
v_nearest.setIntersectVert(false);

geo::Vector h1;
geo::Vector h2;

for (int i = 0; i < p->getEdges().size(); i++)
{
    v = this->getIntersection(r, &p->getEdges().at(i));
    h1.setX(v.getPosition().getX() - r.getOrigin().getPosition().getX());
    h1.setY(v.getPosition().getY() - r.getOrigin().getPosition().getY());
    h2.setX(v_nearest.getPosition().getX() - r.getOrigin().getPosition().getX());
    h2.setY(v_nearest.getPosition().getY() -                     r.getOrigin().getPosition().getY());

    if (i < 1)
        v_nearest = v;
    else if (v.isIntersectVert() == true && h1.getLength() < h2.getLength())
    {
        v_nearest = v;
    }
}
return v_nearest;
}
```

For the Testing i create a Polygon a LightModule and call updateRays and then call the helper-Function callCI(). 
I know my code gets pretty messy when i have to cascade my getters and setters, ill have to fix that but for the Rest i hope everything is understandable and if not feel free to ask. And just to have mentioned it, I Test-draw my Objects with Vertex-Arrays but I don't need Graphical output of the intersection process, i just need the visible polygon.

Just to point out again: I need a faster way of finding the Intersection-Point between a Ray and a Polygon and as I didn't know if i did something wrong in my code I posted it all here so someone can maybe help me making my code more efficient or show me a different method to solve my problem.

Have a nice day and thank you for your answers :)
Paul

EDIT: Would it be meaningfully faster to first triangulate my polygons and then do a Ray-Triangle intersection Test?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume_hierarchy

Comment: So best way would be to quarter the bounding box of each polygon and then subdivide it if necessary?
But i guess i have to subdivide the whole area because the ray could also intersect different polygons

Comment: EDIT: The main drain of performance seems to be the closestintersection function where i have to loop through the polygons...

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the algorithm (which is possibly what you need) but some immediate thoughts on speeding up what you have.

First off you can define **all** your *getters* and *setters* `inline` (put them in the class in the header, not the separate source file) so the compiler can optimize the function calls away.

Then these changes might buy you a few frames:

```
// make sure your getters and setters are inline so the compiler
// can optimize them away
geo::Vertex LightModule::getClosestIntersection(Ray r, geo::Polygon* p)
{
    geo::Vertex v;
    v.setIntersectVert(false);
    geo::Vector h1;
    geo::Vector h2;

    // cache these
    Vector ray_position = r.getOrigin().getPosition();

    geo::Vertex v_nearest(geo::Vector(0, 0));
    v_nearest.setIntersectVert(false);

    // cache size (don't dereference each time)
    size_t size = p->getEdges().size();

    // avoid acces violation
    if(!size)
        return v_nearest;

    // preset item 0
    v_nearest = this->getIntersection(r, &p->getEdges()[0]);

    // start from 1 not 0
    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        // don't use at() its slower
        // v = this->getIntersection(r, &p->getEdges().at(i));
        v = this->getIntersection(r, &p->getEdges()[i]);

        // used cached ray position rather than call functions
        h1.setX(v.getPosition().getX() - ray_position.getX());
        h1.setY(v.getPosition().getY() - ray_position.getY());

        h2.setX(v_nearest.getPosition().getX() - ray_position.getX());
        h2.setY(v_nearest.getPosition().getY() - ray_position.getY());

        // this if not needed because presetting item 0
        //if(i < 1)
        //  v_nearest = v;
        if(v.isIntersectVert() == true && h1.getLength() < h2.getLength())
        {
            v_nearest = v;
        }
    }
    return v_nearest;
}
```

I removed one of the `if` statements by calculating the 0 item before the loop and starting the loop from 1, the rest is just caching a much used value and avoiding `at()` which is slower because it does bound-checking.

Comment: Your code made it better (+50 fps) but its still not near to good :(